# Loading png image texture from char array or QByteArray with libpng

Tags: c++, png, libpng, qbytearray

I have the image data as QByteArray. I want to load the texture of this image from that data using libpng. Everywhere I see reading the image texture from the file or from input stream. But how can I load the image from the QByteArray?? Thanks.

Comment: `bool loadFromData ( const QByteArray & data, const char * format = 0 )` read the docs, they are there for reading

Comment: The real question is: if you're using Qt, why are you trying to use libpng directly? Afaik, the Qt libraries handle png themselves (by using libpng I believe).

Comment: @user1095108 I dont see any method like that in the docs! Thanks for the advice styne666 .I will try it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I wanted in [here](https://forge.ocamlcore.org/scm/viewvc.php/trunk/SRC/loader-libpng.c?logsort=cvs&view=markup&root=glmlite&sortby=date&pathrev=74)  The `png_read_from_mem (png_structp png_ptr, png_bytep data, png_size_t length)' method was exactly what I was looking for. It reads data which is`unsigned char*`.

Comment: I am not getting a struct from png_get_io_ptr(png_ptr);  The subsequent memcpy fails due to invalid address.  Do we need to tell it to use a specific io_ptr struct?